# Destructor is not called for shared_ptr derived class

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, mediator

I want to implement the `Mediator` design pattern using `shared_ptr` for all the program.

Here is the `Mediator interface`:

```
class Mediator
{
    public:
        Mediator(){ print("Mediator()"); }
        virtual void Notify(std::shared_ptr<BaseComponent> sender) const = 0;
};
```

Here is the `ExampleMediator`:

```
class ExampleMediator : public Mediator
{
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<ExampleComponent> eC;
    public:
        void Notify(std::shared_ptr<BaseComponent> sender) const override {
            print("From Example Mediator");
        }
        void setExampleComponent(std::shared_ptr<ExampleComponent> eC_){
            eC = eC_;
        }
};
```

The `ExampleMediator` has a shared pointer to `ExampleComponent` and a method to set it.

This is the base class `BaseComponent`:

```
class BaseComponent
{
    protected:
        std::shared_ptr<Mediator> m;

    public:
        BaseComponent() { print("BaseComponent()"); }
        ~BaseComponent() { print("~BaseComponent()"); }
        void setMediator(std::shared_ptr<Mediator> m_){ m = m_; }
};
```

The `BaseComponent` has a shared pointer to the `ExampleMediator` and a method to set it.

Here is the `ExampleComponent`:

```
class ExampleComponent: public BaseComponent
{
    public:
        ExampleComponent(){ print("ExampleComponent()"); }
        ~ExampleComponent(){ print("~ExampleComponent()"); }
        void doSomethingOnDerived(){ print("ExampleComponent job");}
};
```

The main function:

```
int main()
{

    // Create the mediator
    auto mM = std::make_shared<ExampleMediator>();
    
    // Create the component
    auto eC = std::make_shared<ExampleComponent>();
    eC->setMediator(mM);
    
    // Set the component in the mediator
    mM->setExampleComponent(eC);
}
```

The output is:

```
Mediator()
BaseComponent()
ExampleComponent()
```

If I remove the line `mM->setExampleComponent(eC);` the constructors get called.
Live code in Compiler Explorer: https://godbolt.org/z/E5ofEPGen

My goal is to use the components as shared pointers and not raw pointers, same for the Mediator.

What can be the cause for this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: You created a loop: ExampleMediator and ExampleComponent
have shared pointers referencing each other. therefore both have a refcount of one
and nobody gets freed

Comment: How can I share same `ExampleMediator` to multiple `BaseComponent`s , and set all `BaseComponent`s into the `ExampleMediator` then?

Comment: There are of course many solutions for this.
As written here, that's not possible anyways because both sides don't store a list, right? 
So one side (I assume the mediator) would have a list of components.
This could then list of shared (or even unique) pointers,
whereas the components refering to the mediator could use regular pointers -> no cycle.
Since the mediator "owns" them, he is sure to outlive their pointers -> no use after free.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: @ChrisB , I'm trying to understand your comment, but I need an example if you can. I'm struggling to understand how to do it correctly

Comment: TLDR: Just make the components use a regular pointer, but keep using the shared pointer on the mediator. In general, shared pointers don't allow you to fully stop thinking about your object lifetimes :)

Comment: When I use `weak_ptr` as reference to the component inside the `Mediator` the constructor gets called correctly, is that safe?

Comment: Safe? Sure. You just need somebody else to 'own' your components then.
I don't know your problem domain, but you could make that work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What can be the cause for this issue?

Shared pointers destroy their owned resource when the pointer is the last owner pointing to the resource. When local variable `eC` is destroyed on return of `main`, there is still another owner `mM.eC` so the resource won't be destroyed. Similarly, when the local `mM` is destroyed, its resource is still owned by the resource previously owned by `eC`.

When you own a resource, we typically consider the owner to "depend" on the resource. If we consider objects as nodes and dependency relations as edges, we get a directed graph. This dependency graph should not have loops, because that typically leads to the problem that you encountered.

With shared pointers, one way to break the loop is to weaken the ownership of one node. This can be done by using a weak pointer instead of a shared pointer. Note that you must then take care to handle the case where weakly owned resource has been destroyed before its dependee.